# Unable to fetch String after multiple tags

Tags: regex

I had one string, which has text with multiple lines. In that string I need to fetch the three values using regex. I'm able to fetch first two values. But I'm unable to fetch the third value. Can some one help here to teach me better way of using regex with explanation when we have dynamic tags.

String:

```
<input type='radio' class="radio" id="bb_radio1266767" name='266' value='767'  onclick="show(document.forms[0],window.pageNumber)" />
<!-- Start template -->
</td>
<td class="col_info ">
<label for="bb_radio1266767">
<!-- Start baseProductInfo/displayBaseProductName.ftl-->
 Essential
```

In the above String I need to fetch the **Essential** value, That text will always come out side tags. Before that text I might have multiple number of tags.

Please help here

Comment: I don't see a regex. Did I miss it?

Answer (score 0):

## Two Ways to Extract a String

The first (and better way) is to use the property `.textContent`:

> ```
> document.querySelector('.col_info').textContent;
> ```

The second way is to use regex method `.exec()`

> ```
> const rgx = /Essential/g;
> let res = rgx.exec(str2);
> while (res !== null) {
>   console.log('Using regex.exec(): ' + res[0]);
>   res = rgx.exec(str2);
> }
> ```

You need valid HTML in order to use `.textContent`. I corrected the table and label assuming that your real page has valid HTML. For `.exec()` I took the literal HTML and convert it into a string (just wrap it with backticks  <kbd>**`**</kbd>). Of course this assuming you are doing this manually.

---

### Demo

```js
const str1 = document.querySelector('.col_info').textContent;
console.log('Using .textContent: ' + str1.trim());

const str2 = `<input type='radio' class="radio" id="bb_radio1266767" name='266' value='767'  onclick="show(document.forms[0],window.pageNumber)" />
<!-- Start template -->
</td>
<td class="col_info ">
<label for="bb_radio1266767">
<!-- Start baseProductInfo/displayBaseProductName.ftl-->
 Essential`;

const rgx = /Essential/g;
let res = rgx.exec(str2);
while (res !== null) {
  console.log('Using regex.exec(): ' + res[0]);
  res = rgx.exec(str2);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='radio' class="radio" id="bb_radio1266767" name='266' value='767' onclick="show(document.forms[0],window.pageNumber)" />
      <!-- Start template -->
    </td>
    <td class="col_info ">
      <label for="bb_radio1266767">
<!-- Start baseProductInfo/displayBaseProductName.ftl-->
 Essential
 </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I couldn't see the regex in your answer. Actually the "Essential" word is not a constant one. I may get different value in that place. In such case ' /Essential/g' won't work.

Comment: For instance, For getting name value dynamically I'm using <*name='\d*' regex. Similarly Can help here to find the regex for ''Essential" ?

Comment: "Essential" is **the literal** search word at it's most optimal form. Regex is a pattern to match a multiple possibilities of text. In the demo "Essential" is matched two times in two completely different ways. Your real question should be: *"How can I make a Regex variable?"*